# Why does xlwings send an empty matplotlib plot to Excel when run from IPython or Spyder or Jupyter, but not from a terminal console?

Tags: python, excel, matplotlib, xlwings

I'm running the following Xlwings [code](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/matplotlib.html) from the **Xlwings Matplotlib & Plotly Charts** tutorial.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xlwings as xw

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot([1, 2, 3])

sheet = xw.Book().sheets[0]
sheet.pictures.add(fig, name='MyPlot', update=True)
```

**My setup**

```
Windows 10
Excel from Microsoft 365
Anaconda3 2024.02-1 with
  python 3.11.7
  xlwings 0.29.1
  matplotlib 3.8.0
```

**Expected result**
When the code is typed in and run from the Anaconda Prompt (which is basically cmd.exe with customized environment variables), the figure that is pasted into the Excel worksheet has the axis and the 45-degree line etc.

**Unexpected result**
When the code is typed in and run from IPython or a Spyder console or a Jupyter notebook, the figure that is pasted into the Excel worksheet is blank.

**QUESTION**
Maybe this is a noob question, but I've not been successful in googling for a similar problem description and solution. I have read the Xlwings documentation. Is there an extra line of code that needs to be added when the code is typed out and run from a console that supports graphics instead of when typed out and run from a console that supports only character output?

Comment: I think the answer is [here](https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/1437#issuecomment-708422096). Xlwings is meant to directly interact with Excel on your system. Anaconda prompt is I expect using the python on your computer and interacting with that. Jupyter on the other hand is running in your browser and because of security surrounding you browser, isn't intergrated with the software elsewhere on your system. In Jupyter you use an engine like openpyxl or xlsxwrite or xlread that allows saving Excel files or reading Excel files. The file intermediates are separate from active Excel.

Comment: The code will work with Jupyter, but that's not to say your problem isn't some sort of security setting.